# The right way to make chained observable subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

What is the better way rewriting this code reactively using **RxJS**.

```js
profileInformation;
updateProfile() {
let token;
let profileId = 1;
this.userService.getAccessToken()
    .map((res) => {
        //as I need it multiple times
        token = res;
        return res
    })
    .switchMap(accessToken => this.profleService.getContactIds(accessToken, profileId))
    .subscribe((res) => {
        this.profleService.updateprofile(token, this.profileInformation, res.account.id, res.address.id)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                //do stuff with data
            }, (err) => {
                //do something when err
            })
    }, (err) => {
        //do something when err
    });
})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
updateProfile() {
  let token;
  const profileId = 1;

  this.userService.getAccessToken()
    .do(accessToken => token = accessToken)
    .switchMap(accessToken => this.profleService.getContactIds(accessToken, profileId))
    .flatMap(({account, address}) => this.profleService.updateprofile(token, this.profileInformation, account.id, address.id))
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      //do stuff with data
    }, err => {
      //do something when err
    });
}
```

The reason I have opted for `flatMap` over a second `switchMap` is that 
`switchMap` propagates the first constituent `Observable` that emits a value. In your original code, you were using a nested `subscribe` whose next handler would execute once for each value produced by the inner `Observable`. `flatMap` (AKA `mergeMap`), preserves the original semantics by visiting all values that may be emitted while still unnesting.

*Note if there is only 1 value ever emitted this will not matter but semantically an observable can emit many values and I wanted to preserve that. I also believe it is clearer.*

---

If you are curious about the syntax used in the projection function passed to `flatMap`

```
(({account, address}) => 
  this.profleService.updateprofile(token, this.profileInformation, account.id, address.id)
```

it is known as ES2015 parameter destructuring. It is used to extract properties directly from parameters into local variables. The reason I assume that `account` and `address` are properties of what was `res` is that they were accessed unconditionally. This syntax is often useful in callbacks and general projection functions.

Consider:

```
interface Entity {
  id: number;
}

declare const entities: Entity[];

function getById(entityId: number) {
  return entities.find(({id}) => id === entityId);
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit what you are doing with `flatMap` please refer to my answer

Comment: `switchMap` propagates the first constituent `Observable` that emits a value. In your original code, you were using a nested subscribe whose next handler would execute once for each value produced by the inner `Observable`. Unless I am mistaken (certainly possible) `flatMap` preserves the original semantics by visiting all values that may be emitted while still unnesting. _Note if there is only 1 value ever emitted this will not matter but semantically an observable can emit many values and I wanted to preserve that_

Comment: can you explain this exact part please `{account, address}` why you assume that res will lead to this object? will be so cool if you could tell more info in the answer about the different uses of `flatMap` and `switchMap` operators also why I can't do things inside them so it becomes a better one and that gives me pleasure to mark it as the right one <3

Comment: Thank you, I added additional information and some context and an example around destructuring parameters.

Comment: That's awesome! Kindly you didn't include my last question why some operators don't allow coding inside them `operator()=>{/*code*//*do something*/}`or what the right way to do so?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that when I read your comment. Can you clarify what you mean by _"don't allow coding inside them"_ a wee bit? Are you talking about `do`?

Comment: why can't for example `switchMap((res)=>{console.log(res);
this.aService.doSomething();})`

Comment: You can actually but since you do not return a value from it, the resulting observable will emit `undefined` to subscribers. The type would become `Observable<void>` in typescript.

Comment: That said, the real reason why `flatMap` does not contain the subscribe logic is twofold. **1:** it needs to flatten the observable of observables, so that each inner value is passed to the next operator. **2:** we need something like a `subscribe` somewhere to kick off the observable.

Comment: In the case of the `do` and `switchMap` calls, the logic in `do` could be moved into `switchMap` and then we would remove `do`. It is more idiomatic, however, to perform the side-effecting, or simply logging, logic inside of a dedicated `do` call. That means that `switchMap((res)=>{console.log(res); return this.aService.doSomething();})` (note the return) is perfectly valid

Comment: @Microsmsm I can add these remarks to the answer, but I don't think they necessarily fit the theme of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do switchMap again

```
this.userService.getAccessToken()
  .do(accessToken => token = accessToken)
  .switchMap(accessToken => this.profleService.getContactIds(accessToken, profileId))
  .switchMap(res => this.profleService.updateprofile(token, this.profileInformation, res.account.id, res.address.id))
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }, (err) => {
    });
```

Comment: can I use `do()` instead of `map()` for better look ^^?

Comment: Yes,"do" will work but do not return anything from "do" operator

Comment: why may I need to return something from `do` operator?

Comment: in this case - use map. do - Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return an Observable that is identical to the source.

Comment: Do does not project the stream. the return statement in map was an identity projection so `do` is cleaner. It is also more idiomatic FWIW.

Comment: you can update your answer please so I can mark it as the right one?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this combining the best of two answers @juliapassynkova and @aluanhaddad

```js
profileInformation;
updateProfile() {
    let token;
    let profileId = 1;
    this.userService.getAccessToken()
        //for multiple using token
        .do(accessToken => token = accessToken)
        .switchMap(accessToken => this.profleService.getContactIds(accessToken, profileId))
        .switchMap(res => this.profleService.updateprofile(token, this.profileInformation, res.account.id, res.address.id))
        .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            //do stuff with data
        }, (err) => {
            //do something when err
        })
}
```

Comment: So you determined that `flatMap` was incorrect? I am curious to hear your response to my response :)

Comment: I think I need just the last value only which `switchMap` offers what do you think @AluanHaddad ?

Comment: Well, I think that is true in this particular case, but `switchMap` is a semantic change since the fact that you only wanted the last value is not encoded in the structure of the original program. If you were instead writing a reusable function that operated over some arbitrary observables, `switchMap` would be a breaking change.